# Sum of a series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to show that, $\sum_{n=1}^N 1/n$ $\le$  1 + logN, for N$\ge$5

Comment: Look up the approximation for the Harmonic series

Comment: Isn't it true for all $N?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

For any $ n\ge 2$, and any $ t\in [n-1,n] $,

$$\frac{1}{n}\le \frac 1t \;\implies$$

$$\int_{n-1}^n\frac {dt}{n}\le \int_{n-1}^n\frac{dt}{t} \;\implies$$
$$\frac{1}{n}\le  \ln(n)-\ln(n-1)$$